# Using merlin in vim for coq plugin development in ocaml

Tags: vim, ocaml, coq, ocamlfind, merlin

I installed Coq with opam and want to make a Coq plugin. I managed to compile some plugin examples using `coq_makefile`, but it would be great if I could use merlin in vim for type information and completion for Coq libraries.

Is there a way in which I can add the Coq libraries to ocamlfind?

Comment: I really don't know much about plug-in or merlin, but I know some people on the coq-club mailing list are playing with these packaging methods at the moment. I don't think they often come to SO, so I think you should ask your question on the mailing list also.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I contacted some peple that use merlin in some respos for Coq plugins but I think is a good idea to ask in the mailing list as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`coq_makefile` will now generate a .merlin for you. Just type

```
make .merlin
```

Answer (score 3):

Finally I answered myself. It was onlly necesary to put the directories of the cmi files of coq in the .merlin file with the directive B

```
B path/to/coq/kernel
B path/to/coq/library
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out how to properly use `coq_makefile` to do this and @Nico Lehmann answer didn't work for me.

My `.merlin` file is:

```
FLG -rectypes
S /usr/lib/coq/**
B /usr/lib/coq/**
```

where the first line is important(I have no clue what it means). Of course, change `/usr/lib/` to the path where your coq is. You can find the coq location by running `coqc -where` in the command line.